# Updating a databound gridview using a clickable cell to set a value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am experienced in VB net, but still consider myself new to ASP.net although i have already completed many projects. I have a gridview bound to AccessDataSource in a VB ASP Net page.  The table shows information for each item mainly being dates for each stage. What i would like to be able to do is make one column in the table clickable and when it is clicked the user gets prompted to confirm they would like to set the value and on a "OK" press, the value for that cell is set to the value of Now() in the database and the gridview refreshed.

I have the gridview working well, have managed to make the cell clickable and it ask the user for confirmation. But it is here that i get stuck, regardless of whether the user clicks OK or Cancel, i cant get it to handle the response and i am not sure of how to best handle the update to the cell value. Ideally i would like to keep the code as VB based as possible over. Any advise on the next step would be greatly appreciated.

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ItemGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ItemDataSource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="2" OnRowCommand="ItemGridView_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Item #" SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Project" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="Project" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Item_Size" HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Item_Size" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Finalized" SortExpression="Date_Item_Finalized">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Item_Finalized") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="DateFinalizedRowLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Item_Finalized", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Item_Sent" HeaderText="Sent" SortExpression="Date_Item_Sent" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Item_at_Location1" HeaderText="At Location1" SortExpression="Date_Item_at_Location1" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Left_Location1" HeaderText="Left Location1" SortExpression="Date_Left_Location1" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Item_At_Site_Yard" HeaderText="At Location2" SortExpression="Date_Item_At_Site_Yard" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Item_Left_Site_Yard" HeaderText="Left Location2" SortExpression="Date_Item_Left_Site_Yard" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Item_On_Site" HeaderText="On Site" SortExpression="Date_Item_On_Site" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Days Overdue" SortExpression="Days_Overdue">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Days_Overdue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="DaysOverdueRowLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Get_Days_Overdue(Eval("Date_Item_Finalized"), Eval("Date_Item_At_Site_Yard"), Eval("Date_Left_Location1"))%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Adding Clickable attributes:

```
Protected Sub ItemGridView_Databind_Tasks(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles ItemGridView.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'This section adds a attributes to each cell in the "On Site" column
        e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('Mark Item " & e.Row.Cells(0).Text & " as Onsite. Are You Sure?');")
        e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes.Add("CommandName", "MarkOnSite")
        e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer'")
        e.Row.Cells(9).ToolTip = "Click to mark item as 'On Site'"
    End If
End Sub
```